# Fedora 25 Keyboard not working + KDE Plasma bug

Tags: fedora, drivers, keyboard, plasma5

Fresh install of fedora 25. I have a corsair keyboard which runs on Ubuntu with an open source driver (ckb). On fedora, it doesn't work at all when prompted to decrypt the HDD (I have full disk encryption). I have to plug in a secondary keyboard. If I can get passed the decryption, I can *sometimes* use my corsair keyboard to log in to fedora (it works maybe 25% of the time). If the keyboard works to login, it will work until I restart. The corsair keyboard works 100% of the time in GRUB.

Second problem is that when I login using KDE Plasma DE, the windows will open "frozen-in" to the top left of the screen, being unable to resize, move, or close it. Also, the window is not visible on the launcher. Plus a lot of tearing when I move the "settings" window (it's the only one that will move).

Edit: In regards to the second problem, I have an AMD video card. Also, this is 100% on fedora. KDE works perfectly fine with Ubuntu 16.10.